# Serverless.yml: Reference existing environment variable in another

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a `serverless.yml` which looks like this

```
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  versionFunctions: false

  environment:
    ACCOUNT_ID: "${file(./serverless.env.yml):${self:provider.stage}.account_id}"
    ANOTHER_VARIABLE: "some text ${ACCOUNT_ID} some other text"
```

Here, I want to reference the existing environment `ACCOUNT_ID` in `ANOTHER_VARIABLE`. The `${ACCOUNT_ID}` doesn't work. I also tried to look at the serverless documentation but I'm not able to find anything related to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `${self:provider.environment.ACCOUNT_ID}`.

```
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  versionFunctions: false

  environment:
    ACCOUNT_ID: "${file(./serverless.env.yml):${self:provider.stage}.account_id}"
    ANOTHER_VARIABLE: "some text ${self:provider.environment.ACCOUNT_ID} some other text"
```